# postgres simple number to string mapping

Tags: postgresql, query, case

I have a an `Enum` at the programming language level which is stored as a simple integer on the table. Think:

```
APPLE = 1
GOOGLE = 2
MSFT = 3
AMAZON = 4
 ... (100s more)
```

I just wanna query the table and instead of the number return the corresponding string value. Is there an easier way of doing this without using `case` statement or a temp table:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN "APPLE"
  CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN "GOOGLE"
  CASE WHEN type = 3 THEN "MSFT"
  CASE WHEN type = 4 THEN "AMAZON"
  ...
  ELSE "UNKNOWN"
FROM t
```

Basically it's just a key look-up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO the easiest way is by using a lookup table.

```
create table lk (id int, name text);

insert into lk values
(1, 'apple'),(2, 'google'),(3, 'msft'),(4, 'amazon');

create table t (id serial, lk int);
insert into t (lk) values (2),(1),(3),(4);

select
    t.id,
    lk.name
from   t
join   lk
       on lk.id = t.lk;
```

> ```
> id | name  
> -: | :-----
>  2 | apple 
>  1 | google
>  3 | msft  
>  4 | amazon
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3332124640ffb8a2a170599aceedba12)*

Comment: Thanks. I specifically wanted to avoid temp table but you gave me enough clue.

Comment: You can deal with ENUM postgres type, but to me is quite more difficult than a lookup table

Answer (score 6):

JSON FTW. As a JS developer I'm partial to Object mapping. Here's an example of what that would look like in PG:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
  (
    (json_build_object(
      1, 'APPLE',
      2, 'GOOGLE',
      3, 'MSFT',
      4, 'AMAZON'
    )::jsonb
  )->>(2::text))::text,
  'UNKNOWN'
); 
-- RETURNS 'GOOGLE'
```

Comment: thanks this helped me to map enums integer value back to string

Comment: Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: nice, clean way of mapping enums, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Alright, using @McNets' answer I used `with` clause without having a temp table:

```
create table t (id serial, lk int);
insert into t (lk) values (2),(1),(3),(4);

with m (k, v) as (values (1, 'apple'),(2, 'google'),(3, 'msft'),(4, 'amazon'))
select t.id, m.v
from t
join m
  on m.k = t.lk;
```

Comment: The difference being that the day you need to add a new entry in the mapping you will either need to change your code or some stored procedure/view where the above is contained (same problem by using `CASE`), whereas by using a table you will just need to insert a row, which is low impact. And if your mapping is with hundreds of values as you say, such a `with` statement will not be pretty. You do not need a "temporary" table just create once for all a table with the mapping and you are done forever regarding the design.

Comment: the advantage here is say matching '01' -> 'January'...